# Introduce a ForeignKey filed in my Project Model

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have a system that uses,

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    book_classes = (("","Select"),("1",'F1'),("2",'F2'),("3",'F3'),("4",'F4'))
    b_class = models.CharField('Form',max_length=4,choices=book_classes,default="n/a")
```

I would like to switch it to use a foreignkey from a `Klass` model

```
class Klass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class MyModel(models.Model)
    b_class = models.ForeignKey(Klass,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The system already has a lot of data that uses

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    book_classes = (("","Select"),("1",'F1'),("2",'F2'),("3",'F3'),("4",'F4'))
    b_class = models.CharField('Form',max_length=4,choices=book_classes,default="n/a")
```

What effect will the change have on the already existing data?

Answer (score 1):

It will mess up the data saved in database.
The  `b_class`  is `CharField` now you are converting it to `ForeignKey` which will empty the data.

The best way would be:
1- Export current data to csv.
2- Create new `class Klass`
3- Input the data to new class with same format:
`id = 1 , name = F1`
`id = 2 , name = F2`
`,...`

3- Then convert your `MyModel` to new format.
4- import the data from csv